# Creating Google's CRC32C on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, crc

As the title says.  I'm trying to compile the code found [on Google's Github](https://github.com/google/crc32c).  I don't know much about CMake.  First I ran the following command as per instructions:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I got the following error message:  `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.  After that I tried to run the following build command:

```
cmake -DCRC32C_BUILD_TESTS=0 -DCRC32C_BUILD_BENCHMARKS=0 .. && make all install
```

The output is shown below:

```
l install
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.22.27905.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.22.27905.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_DEPRECATED - Failed
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_SIGN_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Failed
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS
-- Performing Test CRC32C_HAVE_NO_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_PREFETCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_PREFETCH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_MM_PREFETCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_MM_PREFETCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_SSE42
-- Performing Test HAVE_SSE42 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_ARM64_CRC32C
-- Performing Test HAVE_ARM64_CRC32C - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRONG_GETAUXVAL
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRONG_GETAUXVAL - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_WEAK_GETAUXVAL
-- Performing Test HAVE_WEAK_GETAUXVAL - Failed
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:184 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    C:/Source/crc32c-master/third_party/glog

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Source/crc32c-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Source/crc32c-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I looked at the error log, but didn't get much help there.  the third_party/glog directory is empty, so there wasn't any `CMakeLists.txt` file like there should have been.  (The /benchmark and /googletest subdirectories under /third_party were also empty. ?)

Has anybody successfully built this using Visual Studio?  If so, how?

I don't think it matters much, but I'm using VS2019 Community Edition 16.2.5 and CMake 3.15.2.  TIA.

Comment: did you clone the code or download it? Looks like you downloaded it, you need to clone it for the submodules to work

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you very much.  Yes, I didn't clone the code because I don't know anything about git, so I don't know how to do that.  I tried `git https://github.com/google/crc32c.git` but got `error: cannot spawn git-https://github.com/google/crc32c.git: Invalid argument`.  So I dunno.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I spoke too soon.  Looking at GitHub some more, I was able to do the `git clone` command.  Then the submodules seemed to work, so I'm trying the CMake build command again.  It has progressed further, so I'll see what the end result is.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanBirtles  That worked.  I got the error `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`  But it did create the .sln solution file so I was able to bring it up in VS and compile it okay.  Thanks!  If you want the points, you can post this as the answer and I'll flag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan Birtles gave me the correct answer.

I had just downloaded the .zip file, when I needed to do a `git clone` of the files.  After that, everything worked like it was supposed to.  Big thanks to Alan Birtles.